# How to Convert String in format yyyy-MM-dd to Date in same format in Java

Tags: java

I want to convert my String in format 2015-09-07 to Date in format 2015-09-07. While parsing the Date is getting in different format. I need the result Date in same format what the String is.

Thanks&Regards
Sony K Koshy

Comment: use `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: The short answer is, you can't.  You can convert the `String` to a `Date` object, but `Date` has no concept of a format of it's own, it's just a container for the number of milliseconds from a fixed point in time.  You can use a `SimpleDateFormat` to parse and format from/to a `String`, but otherwise you really shouldn't care

Answer (score 1):

Try like this":

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String str = "2015-09-07";
Date dt = sdf.parse(str);
System.out.println(dt);
```

Also refer: [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for details.

Also you can create a generic function like this

```
private Date parseStringToDate(String dt, String format) throws ParseException
{
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    return sdf.parse(dt);
}
```

Comment: see what exactly OP is asking :)

Comment: @Satya:- SimpleDateFormat is what OP is looking for. Right?

Comment: Sorry OP want output should be in `Date` not `String`.

Comment: @Satya:- Updated that! Thanks for pointing it.

Comment: But it is also not an exact answer. `Date` will have all the parts necessary to represent it correctly, including minutes and seconds and so on. So answer is can't. :)

Comment: @Satya... It is possible, because when Date object will be formated, it will have value zero in case of minutes and seconds.

Comment: While parsing the result we get in Differ format. I already try this but no use.

Answer (score 0):

Using `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String dateString = "2015-09-07";
    Date date = simpleDateFormat .parse(dateString);
    System.out.println(date); //Mon Sep 07 00:00:00 CEST 2015
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class StringToDate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("y-MM-dd");
        String stringDate = "2015-09-07";
        try {

            Date date = dateFormat.parse(stringDate);
            System.out.println(date); // it will display Mon Sep 07 00:00:00 IST 2015
            System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));  // it will display 2015-09-07
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```